# How can I run/test Gunicorn with a Python app locally?

Tags: python, gunicorn

I have a Python project that I inherited that is failing in our pipeline because of `Worker terminated due to signal 9`.

I assume it has something to do with Gunicorn but I'm not sure how to replicate it locally. I've tried reading the Gunicorn documentation and it doesn't make sense.

Gunicorn is in the `requirements.txt` file. I don't see anywhere in the project where Gunicorn is referenced/imported. The closest file is `config.py`.

It says with Gunicorn installed, I should be able to use the `gunicorn` command, yet that doesn't work for me. It says that command doesn't exist or something along those lines.

Comment: You typically start `unicorn`from the command line or a script and pass it a reference to the app in a python module. Something like: `gunicorn myapp:app`. Specifically what you pass in will depend on the python app itself.

Answer (score 0):

This works, but I still need to figure out how to shut it down... you can send a signal but I'd prefer something nicer.

```
pip install gunicorn
```

Then in a py file:

```
from _pytest.monkeypatch import MonkeyPatch
from unittest import mock

import threading
import gunicorn.app.wsgiapp

def gunicornapp():
    args = ['gunicorn', 'main:app']
    MonkeyPatch().setenv('FLASK_SECRET_KEY', 'hello')
    MonkeyPatch().setenv('FLASK_ENV', 'development')
    with mock.patch.object(sys, 'argv', args):
        return gunicorn.app.wsgiapp.WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]")

app = gunicornapp()
thread = threading.Thread(target=app.run())
thread.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that you have a `wsgi.py` file in your project directory.

Second make sure you have gunicorn installed: `gunicorn --version`

If you don't have it: `pip install gunicorn`

Then you can run with:

```
gunicorn your_project_name.wsgi:application
```

For example my project is called django_project, so I ran with:

```
gunicorn django_project.wsgi:application
```